# Python code to create list from a file

Tags: python, list, file

I have a dictionary file.txt, with 3 - 5 words in each line.

Like:

```
apple ball back hall
hello bike like
```

I need a python code to put all these words into a list before any other coding occurs.

My idea is to read the file line-by-line, and use `split()`, and `list.append()` functions, but I don't seem to sort it out. Can anyone help?

Edited: Said it the wrong way, sorry!

Comment: Can you post the exact contents of an example file, or at least the first few lines?

Comment: Give and example of input, expected output, actual output, the actual code you've tried, and any error messages.

Comment: You have described the answer already. You could try more yourself.

Comment: What exactly is a `list(dict[ ])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
file_list = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines().rstrip('\n'):
        for word in line.split(' '):
            file_list.append(word)
```

If `file.txt` has the following contents:

```
apple ball back hall
hello bike like
```

The output would be:

```
>>> file_list
['apple', 'ball', 'back', 'hall', 'hello', 'bike', 'like']
```

Comment: I don't understand what OP meant by `list(dict[])`. Do you?

Comment: By that i actually meant that dict is the list var. :P wrong way to say that eh?

Comment: @salmanwahed I'm confused as well. I think he meant dictionary list.

Comment: Pretty sure that's what I want. Let's see how it works.

Comment: Don't shadow the python built-in `list` function, use something like `my_list`

Comment: Errno 2: No such file or directory, although i know file.txt is in the same directory. Also, i am using QPython3 on Android, could that be the problem?

Comment: @Sean , each last word in the list has a '\n' in last. What about that?

Comment: Updated the answer to remove the literal newlines. `file.txt` is just a placeholder name for an arbitrary text file. You should use your own text file. You might wanna try out using absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Comment: @TusharSadhwani Also, if you think this answer has helped, you might wanna press the check mark on the right to help other users as well.